# How to create a dropdown menu on clicking Qaction in PyQt5?

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt, pyqt5

I am making an application where I want to create a dropdown menu if anyone clicks on the Qaction.

My code

```
self.navtb = QToolBar("Navigation")
self.navtb.setIconSize(QSize(25, 25))
self.navtb.setMovable(False)
self.addToolBar(self.navtb)

option_btn = QAction(QIcon(os.path.join('images', 'options.png')), "Option", self)
self.navtb.addAction(option_btn)
```

Comment: Please try to be more clear, QAction is not a UI element, it is used **on** UI elements. What is navtb? Is that a QToolBar? So do you mean that you want to display a menu when the action is clicked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `QAction` can have an associated menu which you can simply set with [setMenu()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qaction.html#setMenu). This menu will pop up (drop down) on click+hold.

Now all you need is to set your button to directly go for the menu on click by [altering its popup mode](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython/PySide6/QtWidgets/QToolButton.html?highlight=qtoolbutton#PySide6.QtWidgets.PySide6.QtWidgets.QToolButton.setPopupMode). Note that while the wording *pop up* is used, the menu will be a proper drop-down menu in a toolbar scenario.

In your example it would roughly translate to:

```py
option_btn.setMenu(...)
self.navtb.widgetForAction(option_btn).setPopupMode(QToolButton.InstantPopup)
```

For reference, this is how I do it in my code in C++:

```cpp
// initialize compute menu and let button display menu without holding mouse
actionComputeDisplay->setMenu(new QMenu(widget));
auto btn = qobject_cast<QToolButton*>(toolBar->widgetForAction(actionComputeDisplay));
btn->setPopupMode(QToolButton::ToolButtonPopupMode::InstantPopup);
```

Comment: Alternatively, if the menu already exists, the [`menu.menuAction()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmenu.html#menuAction) could be added instead.